# 404 error when trying to access Wildfly administration console

Tags: http-status-code-404, wildfly-8

So I have been trying to access the administration console in wildfly but everytime I try this i get an 404 error, however my wildfly is running and I can access any applications I create and publish on the server via eclipse.

I have tried to change ports in standalone.xml and also tried earlier versions of wildfly (I'm currently using 8.2).

I have also managed to to add an user with the add-user.bat and I have no problems whatsoever with this.

Is there anything else I might try?

I have tried the following so far.

I'm currently using Windows 8.1

*Different versions of wildfly
*Deleting wildfly and install it again.
*Changing ports in the standalone.xml and also opening ports via windows.

Comment: Are you trying to access via localhost or by ip/hostname?

Comment: I'm trying to access it with localhost.

Comment: [http://localhost:9990](http://localhost:9990) ?

Comment: I use localhost:8080. When I try to access localhost:9990 the page show that its loading but it never enters the actual page, I also get 404 if i try to reach localhost:9990/console.

Comment: The admin console is on port 9990 by default.

Comment: How are you starting the server?

Comment: I'm starting it with standalone.bat in the bin folder. It' seems like the port that wildfly uses is already used so I'm trying to find which app is reponsible for this. Atleast that's what I can deduce from following error codes. 
15:43:07,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin con
sole is not enabled
15:43:07,786 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8
.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 8708ms - Started 178 of 230 servic

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, I uninstalled nvidias update function and rebooted my system, once I started my wildfly it works like an charm with the correct port 9090. Either way I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

If you trying to access not from localhost, you need:

1. Get port number of **management-http** form standalone/configuration/standalone.xml (default is **9990**):

   ```
   <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
   ```
2. Open access to **management** interface from outside localhost, e.g. change ip from **127.0.0.1** to **0.0.0.0** (listening all your IP addresses):

   ```
   <interface name="management">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
   </interface>
   ```
3. Open http://ip:port/management, e.g. http://kpdesign.ru:9990/management. Login into page.
4. Admin console will be available at http://kpdesign.ru:9990/console

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found an answer of this [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HAL-631).

The answer of jboss support is "Not possible with the current codebase"

So if you need console administration, use Application Server distribution rather than servlet one.

Comment: -1 absolutely. Why do you think that 'bug' has anything to do with this issue? This isn't even a bug you've listed - it's a feature request. Somebody requested a simplified console as an alternative to the current console. There is absolutely nothing in that feature request that indicates there is any problem with the original, other than the reporter wants something simplified and more bare-bones.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I changed jboss.management.http.port in configuration/standalone.xml from 9990 to 9991 (console port) and now is ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you have NVIDIA graphics card, then it's better to change the default port as mentioned by @greatideaPL, since NVIDIA uses the port 9990 by its process `NvNetworkService.exe (NVIDIA Network Service)`.